# Issue in Jquery autocomplete on press of first character

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON output like mentioned below

```
{  
   "responseHeader":{  
      "status":0,
      "QTime":29
   },
   "command":"build",
   "suggest":{  
      "mySuggester":{  
         "a":{  
            "numFound":2,
            "suggestions":[  
               {  
                  "term":"Ajay",
                  "weight":0,
                  "payload":""
               },
               {  
                  "term":"ashish kumar",
                  "weight":0,
                  "payload":""
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I do not get the response when I press the first character the data is
 returned only during second or third character press.Can you please help me
 regarding this.My jquery snippet is as shown below.

```
   $("#name" ).keyup(function(){
         var name = $("#name").val();
         $('#results').html("");

          $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/red/suggest",
              data: "suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q="+name,
              success: function (data1) {
                  console.log("data1"+data1);
                  if (data1 != null) {
                //    alert(data1);
                      var data = JSON.parse(data1);
                      console.log("JSON Parse"+data);
                      var parentNode = data.suggest.mySuggester;
                      var suggestionsNode = null;
                      for (var key in parentNode) {
                          suggestionsNode = parentNode[key].suggestions;
                          if(suggestionsNode!=null)
                              break;
                      }
                      var autocomplete_data = [];
                      $.each(suggestionsNode, function (i, val) {
                          autocomplete_data.push(val.term);
                      });
                      console.log(autocomplete_data);
                      $("#name").autocomplete({
                            source: autocomplete_data  ,
                            select: function(event,ui){

                                 $("#name").val(ui.item.label);
                                 $.ajax({
                                    type: "GET",
                                     url: "http://localhost:8080/Search/search.html",
                                     data: "name=" + ui.item.label,
                                     success: function(response){

                                            // we have the response
                                            $('#results').html(response);
                                             },
                                             error: function(e){
                                             alert('Error: ' + e);
                                         }

                                 });
                            //   return false;
                            }
                        })

                    //return false;
                  }
              },
              error: function(result) {
                  alert("Error");
              }
          })

    });
```

Comment: Did you try setting `minLength: 1` to your `autcomplete`?

Comment: Minlength does not work.

Comment: did you try?? it should as per its **[documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength)**

Answer (score 2):

You're not using autocomplete correctly. You do not need the `keyup` event to get the data for matching items. Autocomplete will do that for you when you set the `source` option for autocomplete to a url that returns JSON.

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
  // autocomplete will add &term=<your term> to this url, so you will need to handle term instead of q
  source: "http://localhost:8983/solr/red/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json",
  select: function(event,ui){

    $("#name").val(ui.item.label);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/Search/search.html",
      data: "name=" + ui.item.label,
      success: function(response){

        // we have the response
        $('#results').html(response);
      },
      error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
      }

    });
    //   return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: If you do want to do the custom ajax call to get the data, source can be set to a function.

Comment: Andrew why does it not return the data for first few characters any suggestions as I do not have access to tweak the code at the server end.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the end result of your code does, but for every keyup event, you make an ajax call and then call autocomplete to initialize it again. Use the `source: function() { }` syntax and make your ajax call inside the function, since you don't have access to change the server.